# jQuery change in width() between 1.7.2 and 1.8.0 where it now returns 0 in this situation?

Tags: jquery, width, version

I have a test website where calls to width() return a non-zero value as expected in jQuery 1.7.2 and earlier, but in newer versions (1.8.0 and later), the function is returning zero.

The problem lies in line 183 of index.html in the web pages listed below:

```
var initialRenderingWidth = $(this).width()
```

... where I am trying to get the computed width of a given span (that I will be replacing with an  tag with the appropriate source)

```
Non-zero - Correct: http://dan.karelia.com/drop/width_152/
zero -   Incorrect: http://dan.karelia.com/drop/width_191/
```

(These compare versions 1.5.2 and 1.9.1, but some tests isolated the change to be at 1.8.0.)

Any jQuery experts out there who can understand why this change happened, if it's a bug or not, and what I might do to work around it?

Comment: Can you strip down the page to the smallest minimal test case (I have a feeling the CSS is important here) and post it on http://jsfiddle.net? The source code of the `width()` and `height()` methods are here (~ line 456): https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/master/src/css.js

Comment: Is the span you're checking visible? Elements that aren't visible will return 0 for all dimensions because they aren't on the page